# Query returning incorrect result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote the below SQL query for pulling the revenue of a specific product Id (500) but it's returning 9335 results but all same (duplicates).

```
DECLARE @ProductID char(3) = '500'

SELECT
    P.ProductID,
    P.Name,
    P.Price,
    S.Quantity,
    CAST(Price * Quantity AS float) AS Revenue
FROM
    Sales  S
INNER JOIN 
    Products P ON S.ProductID = P.ProductID
WHERE
    p.ProductID = @ProductID;
```

Comment: SAmple data and expected results help us help you. You tell us you get 9335 rows, but you don't tell us what results you expect, or what your data looks like.

Comment: This part needs changing: `CAST( Price * Quantity AS float) AS Revenue`: never use floating-point types to represent money! Use `decimal`, `int`-cents, or `money` (but only use `money` if you're careful: https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/avoid-use-money-smallmoney-datatypes ).

Comment: No one can help you debug your code without knowledge of the schema and the data it contains. If you think there are duplicates, then I suggest you add the primary key values from both tables into your query and order by them. That should help you understand the schema, the data it contains, and what your query is actually doing.

Comment: I changed it to int but same result. Is there a way to attach a screen shot for better understanding? There are no dupes in the original table.

Comment: And without aggregation (as already suggested) then one would hope to see multiple rows for EVERY product since that would indicate "good" sales activity. On the otherhand, perhaps your table names do not reflect what one typically finds in tables of similar names.

Comment: Let me circle back after checking it again.

Comment: How much record shld be return for each Productid ?Always 1 row or multiple rows depending upon other factor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want aggregation:

```
SELECT P.ProductID, P.Name, P.Price, 
      SUM(Price*Quantity) as Revenue
FROM Sales S INNER JOIN
     Products P
     ON S.ProductID = P.ProductID 
WHERE p.ProductID = @ProductID
GROUP BY P.ProductID, P.Name, P.Price;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to `GROUP BY` only `S.ProductId` and then `JOIN Products` only after aggregation? I wince every time I see a `GROUP BY` that includes dependent-attributes.

Comment: There are two tables sales and product, the sales table provides quantity sold and the the product table has the price so I am using joins, multiplying price and quantity to get revenue and used float to give accurate value. There are no multiple records for each product in the product table. I don't need the sum

Comment: @Dai . . . Quite possibly, but as with most things, it depends.  In this case, the query returns only one row, so there is not much overhead to the aggregation.

Comment: @khurramShahzad . . . In your question, you are complaining about getting 9,335 different rows in the result set.  The `SUM()` returns just one row, with the sum of all the values.  That seems like a reasonable interpretation of the question.  Note:  converting to `float` does NOT make results more accurate.  In fact, it has the opposite effect.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I am new to the world of SQL so I do not know much, can you please elaborate (or provide a link to a source with explanation) why float brings inaccurate result because in my calculations INT calculates the value withou decimal places and float gives exact values as calculated by a calculator, for example  69.99 * 373 with float gives 26106.27 but INT gives 26106.

Comment: `float` in general is inaccurate due to rounding errors (read about the format in Wikipedia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).  Generally, `decimal`/`numeric` is more accurate.